# Are hardware recommendations considered off topic?

Tags: discussion, support, asking-questions

Fairly straightforward question, I don't want to clutter up the main site if it is.

**Edit:** More specifically, hardware recommendations as it applies to driver support and the like in Ubuntu.  Obviously this isn't the place for general "which CPU is better" questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a question out there already which pretty much encompasses this: [Which computers are guaranteed to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131/which-computers-are-guaranteed-to-work)

Comment: Actually I was more concerned with specific components rather than pre-built machines.  But in essence this answers my question since there are obviously questions on the main site asking about whether or not hardware will run as advertised in Ubuntu.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

They could be on topic, if they are *highly* specialized to your community and specific enough.

You should try one and see what happens -- the fact that you've asked on meta is a good sign!

Comment: I'd say nvidia/ati or intel/AMD are good for the sake of available drivers, MCE/kernel panics, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they are considered off-topic. See https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where it states quite plainly that Shopping or Hardware Recommendations should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

I think some of these are too open ended, for example:

- [What wireless mice work well with Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31183/best-mouse-to-use-on-ubuntu)

However, from my experience hardware information always seems out of date when I search for it and get some out of date information.

Perhaps maybe questions like "What are your experiences with a Foobar 9000?" are more useful, when someone is asking about a specific hardware component?

Comment: I agree that some hardware questions are too broad, but my questions focus more on building a new rig.  As such most of my questions would be more specific (for example, "Which has better driver support: ATI or NVIDIA?" rather than "Best GPU?".  And yes I know that NVIDIA currently blows ATI out of the water on that particular issue, and that ATI is improving quickly.)

Comment: I don't think there's anything we could add to the "nvidia vs. ATI" debate that hasn't been rehashed a million times already on the web. However specific model recommendations we can probably be real good at. *shrug*

Comment: That was meant as an example only, I'm very aware of how much that topic is discussed here and elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a problem with them as long as they are not repeats, or too general.   Which is not saying much.  I think our discomfort with the questions is a good sign.  Be vigilant!  If they seem goofy you can flag them or vote to close.

Really, though, I can imagine them being useful as long as they are well-defined.