# Where else should we direct users for help finding compatible hardware?

Tags: discussion, scope

I gather from the closure of the question [How to find a compatible 10 inch laptop in 2015?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/668905/how-to-find-a-compatible-10-inch-laptop-in-2015) that questions about strategies for finding compatible hardware are not welcome on Ask Ubuntu, even a question that in my opinion follows the guidelines set forth in the answer to the question [What hardware recommendations are okey to ask?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8372/232993). If questions like this do not belong on the Stack Exchange network, then on what site that is not part of the Stack Exchange network should I have asked this question and should others ask similar questions going forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) or the [Ubuntu Discourse site](http://discourse.ubuntu.com) are the two best places to ask questions that don't fit well on Ask Ubuntu. Go check 'em out!